# Creating and Writing a Textfile after Reading a Given File

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, printwriter

The given task is to create a program that:

- Read the file name of the tsv file from the user.
- Open the tsv file and read the student information.
- Compute the average exam score of each student.
- Assign a letter grade to each student based on the average exam score.
- Compute the average of each exam.
- Output the last names, first names, exam scores, and letter grades of the students into a text file named report.txt.
- Output one student per row and separate the values with a tab character.
- Output the average of each exam, with two digits after the decimal point, at the end of report.txt.

I've done everything on this list, and I've tested my code several times. When I print it before writing it in a file, everything works perfectly. But the problem is that when using Fileoutputstream and Printwriter, I don't get a 'report.txt', and the program keeps saying that it produced no output. I've also tried File and Write method, but it still doesn't work. I tried both creating and not creating an actual report.txt file before running the code, and it still doesn't create the damn file. It's driving me crazy. Please help!!!

**Here' my code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  
import java.io.IOException;

public class LabProgram {   
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner reader = null;
  FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;
  
  String fileName = scnr.next();
  fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
  reader = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
  
  String lastName, firstName;
  int score1, score2, score3, individualAvg;
  int studentNum = 0;
  char grade;
  double midterm1, midterm2, midterm3;
  midterm1 = 0.0;
  midterm2 = 0.0;
  midterm3 = 0.0;
  
  FileOutputStream fileStream = null;
  PrintWriter outFS = null;
  
  fileStream = new FileOutputStream("report.txt");
  outFS = new PrintWriter(fileStream); 
 
  while (reader.hasNext()){
        lastName = reader.next();  
        firstName = reader.next();
        score1 = reader.nextInt();
        score2 = reader.nextInt();
        score3 = reader.nextInt();
        
        individualAvg = (score1 + score2 + score3)/3;
        if (individualAvg>=90){
           grade = 'A';  
        }
        else if (individualAvg>=80){
           grade = 'B';
        }
        else if (individualAvg>=70){
           grade = 'C';  
        }
        else if (individualAvg>=60){
           grade = 'D';  
        }
        else{
           grade = 'F';  
        }
        
        midterm1 += score1;
        midterm2 += score2;
        midterm3 += score3;
        studentNum += 1;
        
        outFS.println(lastName + "\t" + firstName + "\t" + score1 + "\t" + score2 + "\t" + score3 + "\t" + grade);
        if (!reader.hasNext()){
           outFS.println("");
           outFS.printf("Averages: Midterm1 %.2f, Midterm2 %.2f, Final %.2f\n", midterm1/studentNum, midterm2/studentNum, midterm3/studentNum);
        }
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Did you close your PrintWriter when you were through using it? `outFS.close();`?

Comment: Hovercraft is right. Use try-with-resources and chain your stream classes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh my god you just saved my life! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome, and now I'm going to help you to solve your next problem that has yet to occur. Please note [my search strategy used to find a useful duplicate question](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+printwriter+not+writing+to+file+site:stackoverflow.com). This type of strategy has helped me find answers to my own coding questions, and will likely help you with your future questions. Much luck!